# Finding substring with javascript when substring is contiguous

Tags: javascript

If am trying to detect the presence of "http" in a string. I am trying this:

```
 url_value = http://yadda/yaddayadda/a_site
 substring = "http";
 substring_b = "https";
 if(url_value.includes(substring) == false || url_value.includes(substring_b) == false) { url_value = substring + url_value  };
```

I want to attach the http to the string if it is missing.

Comment: There seems some redundancy. Every time https is found to be there, http would also be found. So, you can place one check instead to check for http only. Or you may be trying to check for some other condition. Please describe when "do something" should run and when it should not.

Comment: condition should be == true

Comment: try indexOf() if(url_value.indexOf(substring) === -1) means not present

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
     url_value = 'http://yadda/yaddayadda/a_site';
     substring = "http";
     substring_b = "https";
     if(url_value.indexOf(substring) >= 0 || url_value.indexOf(substring_b) >= 0)    { 
  **do something** 
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {

     
      url_value = 'http://yadda/yaddayadda/a_site';
     substring = "http";
     if(url_value.search(substring) >= 0 ) { 
  alert("HELLO");
     };  
     
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I could get to work:

```
 if(url_value.substring(0,4) != substring && url_value.substring(0,5) != substring_b) { url_value = substring + url_value };
```

Answer (score 0):

use indexOf()

```
url_value = http://yadda/yaddayadda/a_site
substring = "http";
substring_b = "https";
if(url_value.indexOf(substring) !== -1 || url_value.indexOf(substring_b) !== -1) { url_value = substring + url_value  };
```